# Blender Cycles Viewport Preview taking too long

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I am a user about 6 months into blender. Earlier I was doing my work on an i5 6200U with Intel HD 520, and now I have moved to a i5 7200U with Intel HD 620 graphics.

My cycles viewport rendering (you know, the noisy rendering if you move around the scene with cycles on) was pretty average on the i5 6200u, but now as I have moved to the new one, I am getting much slower viewport renders, although there is nothing to complain about the final image renders.

Viewport renders themselves, even on a simple scene, takes around 50 seconds to completely denoise! I have turned out viewport samples, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You can not expect much from this low-end setup. Make sure latest drivers installed and I guess that's all what you can do...

Comment: @brockmann Well recently I upgraded to a GeForce GTX 1660 and i7 4770 processor, things are going really smooth.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a question about the performance of your specific components, which the Blender Stack Exchange is not able to help with as much.

You can reduce the viewport sample number (the default is 16) to shorten the time that it take to render (as you mentioned you did). You can also reduce the render samples and/or resolution of the camera to speed up the rendering process for rendering a final image or animation.

Here are a few things that may be causing slow viewport rendering times (not an exhaustive list):

- Scenes with lots of objects and textures (remove any objects if possible)
- Objects with high vertex/face count (use the minimum number of vertices possible)
- High resolution textures on objects
- Other applications using processor(s) in the background.

You can try fixing any of the above problems, edit using solid or material preview mode, and/or do your editing and modeling in Eevee before doing final edits and renders in Cycles.